# How to continuously check if user login to other device with same details in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working with flutter app in which I have integrated login and logout functionality from Rest API. Now I want to add functionality like whatsapp that if user login on new device with same login details that it should logout from current device. Can someone tell me the way how do I achieve this in flutter app ? Thanks

Comment: You invalidate the old auth-token and issue a new one. Do that on the server.

Answer (score 3):

I think this function should be implement on Server, when user login on new device, Server will revoke old token and refresh token.

When user open app on old device -> they will get respone 401 and can't continue use application.

Comment: Yes I know that should be implemented on server. But as you said when user open app. I want to do that like whatsapp. Even app is running and user create account on other phone it notifies in between. Thats exactly I want

Comment: it mean you want it real time ?  I don't use Whatsapp. But you mean it real time I think we can use FCM. Server can send a notification to old device when have new device added.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks. I will check into FCM